# Flutter: vertically align each column in a Row in different ways (top, center, bottom)

Tags: flutter, alignment, row

I would like to vertically align each column in a Row widget in a different way:

1. First column must be aligned at the top.
2. Second column doesn't matter, but it could be centered.
3. Third column must be aligned at the bottom.

[image]

Row widget only gives the option to align **all** of it's columns in the same way:

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: []
)
```

Important: this Row has a dynamic height, according to the contents of the central column.

I have already tried it in many ways, but without success. I would appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some difficulties replicating the same UI but in the end that's how it turned out:

```dart
            IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      children: const [
                        Text("text, text, text"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                        "text, text, text,text, text, text,text, text, text,text, text, text,text, text, text,text, text, text,text, text, text,text, text, text"),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: const [
                        Text("text, text, text"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

The `IntrinsicHeight` gives all the `Row`'s child the same height.

Here's a running example:
https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zn00679n106?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart